# Como fazer com que um arquivo PDF no assets do meu APP seja aberto pelo leitor de PDF nativo do android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um APP que precisa abrir alguns arquivos PDF (leis) que deve vir junto com a aplicação.

A ideia é chamar uma Intent para abrir estes arquivos PDF pelo próprio leitor PDF nativo do Android ou um leitor de PDF já instalado no celular. Os arquivos estão no assets (dentro do diretório res). Como faço para a aplicação abrir o leitor de PDF externo e a intenção abrir o PdF com o caminho do arquivo que esta no assets?

Já tentei várias coisas e ainda não consegui.
Por favor, me ajudem!

Comment: Tem algum código que consiga mostrar para dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Seria como o APP Bombeiros IT-instruções Tecnicas (Ele abre a legislação em um visualizador de PDF onde tem campo de buscas do próprio leitor de PDF).

Answer (score 0):

`file://android_asset` é visível apenas para o seu app. Você está querendo que outro aplicativo abra um arquivo da pasta `assets` que ele não possui.

O que você pode fazer é copiar esse arquivo para o diretório interno ou externo e ai tentar ler o mesmo.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Você tem algum código assim?

Comment: Algo assim: https://gist.github.com/alhazmy13/c93c5e083ec0b7fe6d1c

Comment: Não esqueça das permissões de `READ` and `WRITE`

Comment: Acho que é isso ai. Mas como ficaria o meu xml?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: No exemplo que você me passou, como faço para chamar o método openPDFFiles (Como informado no item 5)?

Comment: `openPDFFiles("file.pdf")`

Comment: Nossa, ao clicar no botão ele aciona o leitor de PDF e depois volta para o APP com a seguinte mensagem: Não foi possível acessar o arquivo. Verifique a localização ou a rede e tente novamente.

Comment: Fiz uma outra pergunta com o código no seguinte link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309949/como-abrir-um-arquivo-pdf-que-esta-no-assets-do-meu-app-em-um-leitor-de-pdf-j%C3%A1

Comment: Desculpa pelo incômodo, mas, por favor, verifica o que fiz de errado.