# Como abrir um arquivo PDF, que esta no assets do meu APP, em um leitor de PDF já instalado no celular?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um APP que precisa abrir alguns arquivos PDF (leis) que deve vir junto com a aplicação.

A ideia é chamar uma `Intent` para abrir estes arquivos PDF pelo próprio leitor de PDF já instalado no celular. Os arquivos estão no assets. Como faço para a intenção abrir o PDF com o caminho do arquivo que esta no assets?

Aqui no site foi me passado, como exemplo, o seguinte link:
https://gist.github.com/alhazmy13/c93c5e083ec0b7fe6d1c

Através do exemplo acima fiz o que segue abaixo no `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.vdtecnologia.br.pdfassets;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    Button btn1;
    private String TAG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                openPDFFiles("AnexoI.pdf");


            }
        });



    }



    private void openPDFFiles(String AnexoI) //fileName is the pdf file name which is keep in assets folder. ex file.pdf
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "");
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(AnexoI);
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), MODE_PRIVATE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/"+AnexoI), "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (RuntimeException ex){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Não foi encontrado nenhum leitor de PDF no seu dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException

    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)

        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Mas ao clicar no botão ele aciona o leitor de PDF e depois volta para o APP com a seguinte mensagem:

> Não foi possível acessar o arquivo. Verifique a localização ou a rede e tente novamente.

Answer (score -1):

Troque o nivel do seu PDF de assets para raw e tente isso.

```
protected void openPDF() {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
            try{
                Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                m.invoke(null);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource("CAMINHO DO SEU ASSETS(RAW)");

        try
        {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.pdf"));
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        Intent share = new Intent();
        share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        share.setType("application/pdf");
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "NOME_DO_AQUIVO.pdf");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(path);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(share);
    }
```

Comment: Boa noite! Como faço isso trocar o nível do pdf de assets para raw?

Comment: Criei a pasta raw. Ocorre que esta dando erro na codificação onde você mandou colocar "O CAMINHO DO SEU ASSETS (RAW)".

Comment: Na linha ficou assim: File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(Integer.parseInt("res/raw"));

Comment: Mas o APP não funciona. Simplesmente fecha com a mensagem que o app parou. Não sei se o caminho para a pasta raw (que esta dentro da pasta res) esta correto.

Comment: coloque R.raw.nome_do_pdf

Comment: Fiz o que você disse, mas não funcionou. O app continua fechando com a mensagem que o app parou.